# Adding an existing view to content nodes sorted by taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm setting up a webshop with a pre-made theme I bought. My issues is the following:

I'm trying to set up the product grid so it can be filtered by product types, which I store in a vocabulary.

I added a menu to the product grid page using the Taxonomy Menu module, which creates a menu block from a vocabulary, and the menu links lead to pages where products display sorted by the taxonomy terms assigned to them. It's not really filtered, tho, the path is mysite.com/vocabularyname/termname - so, it's all the nodes with the term assigned to them.

The theme has a neat view for the product grid, however, when I click on any item in my menu, the page, altohugh filtered properly, does not appear with the same layout, it's only fields thrown on top of each other, and I can't seem to be able to assign the same view to those pages.

I tried cloning the page display of the original grid and setting the view path to the URL of the pages sorted by the taxonomy terms (smt like this: mysite.com/vocabualryname/*). Is it the right approach at all? Or am I missing something, contextual filter, or otherwise?

It might be a really basic issue, all the better for me, I'm quite new to drupal.

Comment: Found the solution, I had to play around with contextual filters on the view, copying the contextual filter settings of the disabled, default drupal taxonomy term view to the custom grid view and than change the path to /taxonomy/term/% , and ofc disable the core taxonomy term view again.